# jQuery select next closest class

Tags: jquery

I have a simple list of FAQ's

```
<div class='qcontainer'>
    <p>Q:</p>
    <div class='question'>Question</div>
</div>
<div class='acontainer'>
    <p>A:</p>
    <div class='answer'><p>Answer</p></div>
</div>
<div class='qcontainer'>
    <p>Q:</p>
    <div class='question'>Question</div>
</div>
<div class='acontainer'>
    <p>A:</p>
    <div class='answer'><p>Answer</p></div>
</div>
```

All I am trying to do is a toggle the visable state of the next answerr when the question is clicked.

So far I have got

```
   $('.qcontainer').bind("click", function (e) {
        $('.qcontainer').next('.acontainer').toggle(400);
    });
```

But this toggles all the items, what i want to do is just target teh answer for the clicked  question. so the next item in the list from the clicked object.

Comment: FYI, if you're using a more recent version of jQuery, `.delegate()` and especially `.on()` are preferred over `.bind()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like below,

```
$('.qcontainer').bind("click", function (e) {
    $(this).next().toggle(400);
});
```

For the markup you have, `.next` of `qcontainer` is `acontainer` and so you can simply use `.next` to toggle `acontainer` and not worry about a thing :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.qcontainer').bind("click", function (e) {
        $('.acontainer:visible').hide(0);
        $(this).nextAll('.acontainer').show(400);
    });
```

Comment: I like the collapse all open questions. nice touch.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you were close!

```
$('.qcontainer').bind("click", function () {
    $(this).next('.acontainer').toggle(400);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, tell me if it works. In the answer DIV you have one unclosed "DIV".

```
    <div class='qcontainer'>
        <p>Q:1</p>
        <div class='question'>Question</div>
    </div>
    <div class='acontainer'>
        <p>A:</p>
        <div class='answer'><p>Answer</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class='qcontainer'>
        <p>Q:2</p>
        <div class='question'>Question</div>
    </div>
    <div class='acontainer'>
        <p>A:</p>
        <div class='answer'><p>Answer</p></div>
    </div>
```